# List of substrings

Tags: python, regex, string, list, tags

I have big string, it can have a few thousands lines. I would like to to get all sub-strings like: `[tag] here can be everything [/tag]` in a list.

How can I do this? My regex is not working (or I'm doing something wrong).

Comment: Does it have a particular format?  From the question, it looks a little like BBCode.

Comment: Could you convert `[]` to `<>` and use some XML parser?

Answer (score 0):

The function `find_all_tags` returns a list of all occurences of tag `tag` in `text`:

```
import re
def find_all_tags(text, tag):
    return re.findall(r"(?s)\[" + tag + r"\].*?\[/" + tag + r"\]", text)

>>> text="""this is [b]bold text[/b] and some[b]
that spans a line[/b] some [i]italics[/i] and some
[b][i]bold italics[/i][/b]"""
>>> find_all_tags(text, "b")
['[b]bold text[/b]', '[b]\nthat spans a line[/b]', '[b][i]bold italics[/i][/b]']
```

Tell me if you need something different (e.g a generator instead of a list of the substrings)

Comment: I would like to know how can my answer be judged as “not useful” and be worthy of a downvote; AFAIU, it's exactly what the question requested.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use string splits

```
for item in my_big_string.split("]"):
    if "[" in item:
         print item.split("[")[-1]
```

eg

```
>>> text="""this is [b]bold text[/b] and some[b]
... that spans a line[/b] some [i]italics[/i] and some
... [b][i]bold italics[/i][/b]"""

>>> for item in text.split("]"):
...    if "[" in item:
...        print item.split("[")[-1],
...
b /b b /b i /i b i /i /b
>>>
```